# Shrink Header for UICollectionView and UITableView

Tags: swift, layout

I am trying to create a header for a UICollectionView and UITableView that has a search bar and label and when a user goes down on a scroll view the search bar and label header will shrink. The image link below is exactly what I want it to look like. I've tried looking through multiple resources to accomplish this, such as Github, but I don't really know how to set up those projects.

[FlexableHeader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5mUs.gif)

Comment: How about this library: https://github.com/maxep/MXParallaxHeader?

Answer (score 0):

Just go through the ReadME file and use the thirdparty library, one which I know: https://github.com/apping/APParallaxHeader. 
You can use this in your project via cocoa pods, for more detail go through the page it has all the details.